# How to send a POST request from GTM custom tag template?

Tags: google-tag-manager

I'm developing a simple custom tag template for Google Tag Manager. It's supposed to bind to some events and send event data to our servers as JSON in the body of a POST request.

The sandboxed [GTM Javascript runtime](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/templates/api#injectscript) provides the [sendPixel()](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/templates/api#sendpixel) API. However, that only provides GET requests.

How one sends a POST request from within this sandboxed runtime?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Nope. It seems that it is not possible for now. We eneded up implementing our 'tag' outside of the GTM sandbox and the Tag manager template gallery. Instead we implemented a script that binds to the data layer itself using the https://github.com/google/data-layer-helper. But we were only aiming for a website we own. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a combination of the injectScript and copyFromWindow APIs found here [Custom Template APIs](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/templates/api#geturl).

Basically, the workflow goes like this.

1. Build a simple script that contains a function attached to the window object that sends a normal XHR post request. The script I made and use can be found here: https://storage.googleapis.com/common-scripts/basicMethods.js
2. Upload that script somewhere publically accessible so you can import it into your template.
3. Use the injectScript API to add the script to your custom template.
4. The injectScript API wants you to provide an onSuccess callback function. Within that function, use the copyWindow api to grab the post request function you created in your script and save it as a variable.
5. You can now use that variable to send a post request the same way you would use a normal JS function.

The script I included above also includes JSON encode and Base64 encode functions which you can use the same way via the copyWindow api.

I hope that helps. If you need some specific code examples for parts I can help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I knew this is possible but since we already have a control over the target website we can inject the script directly. However your answer may be useful to folks who need to send POST requests from a tag that is supposed to be included by a third parties. I'm therefore accepting this answer.

Answer (score 4):

According to @Ian Mitchell answer - I've made similar solution.

This is the basic code pattern that can be used inside GTM template code section in such as scenario:

```
const injectScript = require('injectScript');
const callInWindow = require('callInWindow');
const log = require('logToConsole');
const queryPermission = require('queryPermission');
 
const postScriptUrl = 'https://myPostScriptUrl'; //provide your script url
const endpoint = 'https://myEndpoint'; //provide your endpoint url
  
//provide your data; data object contains all properties from fields tab of the GTM template
const data = {
  sessionId: data.sessionId,
  name: data.name,
  description: data.description
};
 
//add appropriate permission to inject script from 'https://myPostScriptUrl' url in GTM template's privileges tab
if (queryPermission('inject_script', postScriptUrl)) {
  injectScript(postScriptUrl, onSuccess, data.gtmOnFailure, postScriptUrl);
} else {
  log('postScriptUrl: Script load failed due to permissions mismatch.');
  data.gtmOnFailure();
}
 
function onSuccess() {
  //add appropriate permission to call `sendData` variable in GTM template's privileges tab
  callInWindow('sendData', gtmData, endpoint);
  data.gtmOnSuccess();
}
```

It's important to remember to add all necessary privillages inside GTM template. Appropriate permissions will show automatically in privillages tab after use pertinent options inside code section.

Your script at 'https://myPostScriptUrl' may looks like this:

```
function sendData(data, endpoint) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var stringifiedData = JSON.stringify(data);

  xhr.open('POST', endpoint);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
  xhr.send(stringifiedData);

  xhr.onload = function () {
    if (xhr.status.toString()[0] !== '2') {
      console.error(xhr.status + '> ' + xhr.statusText);
    }
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not strictly necessary to load an external script. While still a workaround, you can also pass a fetch reference into the tag through a "JavaScript Variable" type variable:

1. Create a GTM variable of type "JavaScript Variable" with the content "fetch", thus referencing "window.fetch"
2. Add a text field to your Custom Tag, e. g. named "js.fetchReference".
3. Use data.fetchReference in your Custom Tag's like you normally would use window.fetch
4. Make sure the tag instance actually references the variable created in step 2 with {{js.fetchReference}}

I jotted this down with screenshots at https://hume.dev/articles/post-request-custom-template/

Comment: Looks good, but I get the following: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Illegal invocation. Any likely cause?

Comment: That sounds rather like an issue with your specific use of fetch than with the process in general.
Does your code work as expected in a "regular" JS enviroment, e. g. if you execute it in your browser's JS console?